# writing your own openscap scan profile

Tags: linux, openscap

I am currently checking the remote machine using the command `oscap-ssh login@host 22 xccdf eval -- profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_standart --report name.html`.

But the test templates don't suit me, I only need to check three conditions, for this I need to create my profile, so I ask how this can be achieved?

Comment: Scanning what with what?

Comment: I need openscap to do the checks that I need, not the ones that are in the template. For example, I need him to check for the presence of a file in the directory

Comment: Please edit your question to include all details of what you want to achieve and what your problem is.

Comment: I am currently checking the remote machine using the command oscap-ssh login@host 22 xccdf eval -- profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_standart --report name.html . But the test templates don't suit me, I only need to check three conditions, for this I need to create my profile, so I ask how this can be achieved?

Comment: Now that's a question someone can answer ... but not me. I started a vote to reopen your quesition, I'm sure someone will be able to answer it when it is open again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the scap-workbench gui on a system with a desktop.

https://www.open-scap.org/tools/scap-workbench/

It gives you the option to only select the items you want to test for and save it as a profile.