# Editing Scan profiles

Tags: linux

I am currently checking the remote machine using the command oscap-ssh login@host 22 xccdf eval -- profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_standart --report name.html .

But ready-made templates don't suit me, I only need to check three conditions, for this I need to create my own scan profile, how can this be done? I am grateful in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [writing your own openscap scan profile](https://serverfault.com/questions/1103846/writing-your-own-openscap-scan-profile)

Comment: Please don't repost your question. It's already in the process of being reopened.

Comment: Has no one ever asked such a question?